# SUMIF with VLOOKUP function excel, adding all values with the same ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, sumifs

So I believe I need to be using a vlookup/sumif combo here but i can't wrap my head around the notation. I have two tables that look something like this:

Table 1:

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
|  CO   |  Week 1  |  Week 2  |  Week 3  |  Week 4 |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
| 1234  |          |          |          |         |
| 2345  |          |          |          |         |
| 3456  |          |          |          |         |
| 4567  |          |          |          |         |
| 5678  |          |          |          |         |
| 6789  |          |          |          |         |
```

Table 2:

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  CO   |  Week 1  |  Week 2  |  Week 3  |  Week 4  |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1234  |    10    |    25    |    20    |     10   |
| 1234  |    20    |    25    |    20    |     10   |
| 1234  |    30    |    25    |    10    |     15   |
| 2345  |    10    |    25    |    10    |     10   |
| 1234  |    40    |    25    |    15    |     15   |
| 6789  |    25    |    25    |    20    |     20   |
| 1234  |    10    |    25    |    20    |     10   |
| 6789  |    20    |    25    |    20    |     10   |
| 3456  |    30    |    25    |    10    |     15   |
| 4567  |    10    |    25    |    10    |     10   |
| 5678  |    40    |    25    |    15    |     15   |
| 4567  |    25    |    25    |    20    |     20   |
```

So in table 1, I need to sum up all values of week 1/2/3/4 for the respective "CO". Thank you advance for anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are making this too hard:

In the first cell under Week 1 (assuming cell B2), put:

```
=sumif(Table2!$A$2:$A$500, A$2, Table2!B$2:B$500)
```

You can copy that across and down and it should tally up your totals.

Comment: I'm so happy I could cry!! I can't believe i overlooked this question, been up a good 20 hours now. Thank you sooooo much!

Answer (score 1):

[image: table]

we also use `SUM`, `OFFSET` AND `MATCH` FUNCTION to solve this problem

```
=SUM(OFFSET(H$10,MATCH($A11,$G$11:$G$22,0),0,MATCH($A11,$G$11:$G$22,1)-MATCH($A11,$G$11:$G$22,0)+1))
```